# Intent URI not clickable

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I would like to be able to open my application using link provided in SMS. I created following intent filter but it is not clickable in messaging app.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="sampleapp" />
    <data android:host="smsverification" />
</intent-filter>
```

It does not work until I change scheme to `http` or `https`.

Maybe there might be just error in the sent message?

`sampleapp://smsverification/data?value=123&code=abc`

Comment: try using sampleapp://smsverification uri since you haven't mentioned "/data" as android:pathPrefix in your manifest

Comment: That's just a minor issue but I know about it. Main issue is, that link is not clickable until it is http schema

Comment: look at the CommonsWare solution. I think he is talking about the same thing as you are facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193683/android-deep-linking-issue-how-to-use-custom-url-scheme-myapp-some-data

Comment: Seems to me like it's not possible to solve it without having `http` scheme

Comment: Will this be of any help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328387/can-we-pass-a-uri-in-an-sms-message-instead-of-hyperlink-in-android

Comment: No, still no progress. But I'll keep it as an `http`. It is not clickable if I use custom scheme.

Comment: @JakubGruber How did you achieve this without making the browser open the http url mentioned?
Have you done something like this to grab the intent?
`<data android:scheme="http" android:host="sampleapp">`

Comment: Yes, it needs to look like URL link